# payload limit for S3 API Gateway is 10 MB, Still, Why I am able to upload file more than 10 Mb?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3

As per [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html), we have a payload limit of 10Mb. But, using S3 java API I am able to upload file more than 10 Mb. I am not able to understand this.

Comment: Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 and API Gateway are two independent services.

If you are using the Java SDK to access S3, then you are not using API Gateway, and not subject to its limits.  [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) is a separate service that allows you to build custom APIs, including endpoints that can proxy intact or transformed requests to other services, including S3, in which case the transfers are subject to the documented limits for the gateway.

If you are invoking an [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function from API Gateway, the limit only applies to the request and response payloads in and out of the function through the gateway.  The function code itself can access S3 with the SDK and exchange arbitrarily large payloads with S3 -- it just can't accept a request body or render a response body that exceeds the payload limits of APi Gateway or the Lambda service.